# Copying Invoice data to Sales Book, Macro not working...Aaargh

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to save "Invoice" data to "Salesbook" in excel workbook. The code I have is not working.  Any help would be marvelous. Excel is saying Identifier Not Recognised...but why? it is! isn't it? ... Here's the code-

Note- The code below works. The problem was my sheet name had a 'space' at the end, hence the identifier not recognizing it. ffs.

```
Sub UpdateSalesBook()
  Dim rng As Range
  Dim i As Long
  Dim a As Long
  Dim rng_dest As Range
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  i = 1
  Set rng_dest = Sheets("Sales Book").Range("D:F")
  ' Find first empty row in columns D:G on sheet Sales Book
  Do Until WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng_dest.Rows(i)) = 0
    i = i + 1
  Loop
  'Copy range A23:D27 on sheet Invoice to Variant array
  **Set rng = Sheets("Invoice").Range("A23:D27")** 'This is what excel doesn't recognise
  ' Copy rows containing values to sheet Sales Book
  For a = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng.Rows(a)) <> 0 Then
      rng_dest.Rows(i).Value = rng.Rows(a).Value
      'Copy Invoice number
      Sheets("Sales Book").Range("A" & i).Value = Sheets("Invoice").Range("C18").Value
      'Copy Date
      Sheets("Sales Book").Range("B" & i).Value = Sheets("Invoice").Range("C15").Value
      'Copy Company name
      Sheets("Sales Book").Range("C" & i).Value = Sheets("Invoice").Range("A7").Value
      i = i + 1
    End If
 Next a
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: on which row of code does it fail?

Comment: Have you tried using `WorkSheets("Invoice").Range` etc? or fully qualified as `ActiveWorkBook.Worksheets("Invoice").Range` etc?

Comment: As @MiguelH said, most of these issue come about because references are not qualified. I would first qualify your shee (i.e. **`Dim oWS As Worksheet: Set oWS = Thisworkbook.Worksheets("Invoice")`**. Now you can try: **`Set rng = oWS.Range("A23:D27")`**

Comment: Your code works for me.  That's a very strange error to get on the line you highlighted.  Perhaps there is some weird unprintable character in the line - you could try deleting and re-typing it.

Comment: @Zac Can you show me where this would go in the code block please? Dim at top with other Dims, but where do the Sets go?

Comment: @RealCheeseLord Look at the middle of the codeblock for this-  **Set rng = Sheets("Invoice").Range("A23:D27")** 'This is what excel doesn't recognise

Comment: Change `Set rng = Sheets("Invoice").Range("A23:D27")` with `Set rng = oWS.Range("A23:D27")`

Comment: @YowE3K you were right. The strange character however was not in the code but in the name of the sheet. I had pressed the space bar at the end of 'invoice'. This made it unrecognizable. grr

Comment: @Peter That is still weird - an unrecognised sheet name should give a "Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range" error.  (But, as long as it now works, all we can do is shrug our shoulders and wonder at the vagaries of VBA.)